# Python OOP - method able to build an object that inherit from the first class object

Tags: python, oop

I am a real newbie, so I'm sorry if my title question is not well defined. I have a class 'World' and a class 'House'. There is a method in the class 'World' to build 'House' objects. I would like not being forced to copy the 'World' object attributes to the 'Houses' objects since there is a lot of attributes and a lot of 'House' objects.

```
import numpy as np


class House:
    
    def __init__(self,coordinates):
        self.coordinates = coordinates

        
        
class World:
    
    def __init__(self,name,x,y): # Please imagine a lot of attributes
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def Add_A_Bunch_Of_Houses(self,n):
        house_x = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=self.x,size=n)
        house_y = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=self.y,size=n)
        house_coordinates = zip(house_x,house_y)
        self.HOUSES = [House(coords) for coords in house_coordinates]
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to access the 'fantastic_world' attributes in a 'House' object, like the following :

```
fantastic_world = World("narnia",5,5)
fantastic_world.Add_A_Bunch_Of_Houses(10000)
fantastic_world.HOUSES[6678].world_name # does not work obviously
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick answer, since I am not sure what is your actual need, so I can update the answer upon further exchange with you if needed.

First of all, you can always pass **World** instance as a parameter to new houses. That would be the quickest fix. For example:

```py
class House:
    def __init__(self,coordinates,world=None):
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.world = world  # <-- a new field that will hold the reference to world if given


class World:
    def __init__(self,name,x,y): # Please imagine a lot of attributes
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def Add_A_Bunch_Of_Houses(self,n):
        house_x = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=self.x,size=n)
        house_y = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=self.y,size=n)
        house_coordinates = zip(house_x,house_y)
        self.HOUSES = [House(coords,self) for coords in house_coordinates] # <-- mind the self. This is the actual World instance
```

In this way, you can instantiate a House with optional **world** parameter, that will point to the "parent" class (mind it is not a parent class in OOP terms).

This way you may access the field via:

```py
fantastic_world = World("narnia",5,5)
fantastic_world.Add_A_Bunch_Of_Houses(10000)
fantastic_world.HOUSES[6678].world # <-- you obviously have access to World instance now. So name would be retrieved by:
fantastic_world.HOUSES[6678].world.name
```

This is a quick and dirty solution. But it is not really OOP. You might consider using a database and an ORM (foreign keys would work nicely here).

You may also consider a different design, where you inherit classes or use Mixin to extend them.

Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: I just disagree that this is not OOP, or that it is *quick and dirty*. It is not *inheritance*.

Comment: `House` instances can now optionally *have a* `World` (by storing a reference to it). *has a* is just as valid and common as an OOP concept, as the `is a` concept.

Comment: Using a database deals with the storage implementation problem, and the ORM makes the magic of dealing with it at an upper, object-oriented level. I think what you mean is that at the object level, as is, it is not expressed that `self.world`  is a foreign key. But that is an implementation detail if using a database.

Comment: I agree, that stating it is not really OOP is too strong of wording from my part. It is completely legit and that is why I gave this answer. The design presented in the OP question hints at a potentially rather large project with many Entities that will need to be represented in a way. This is why I raised my concern, that my solution might not be the best design decision, but without more information, it is hard to give a more specific alternative. But I agree with your objection @progmatico

Comment: Regarding database, it is completely true, that it is a particular solution to a very particular problem and at the same time it doesn't really say anything about OOP. It might be unnecessary for the given project, but I just felt it might be relevant to hint at this option. And yes, my concern is that at the object level `self.world` might need some additional infrastructure around it in House objects, to make it more dev-friendly down the road.